# How do I mock RxJs 6 timer?

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs6

We've recently updated from Angular 5 to Angular 6, and with it RxJs 6.
As part of the migration, the timer usage has changed from:

```
Observable.timer()
```

to

```
timer()
```

There are a number of places in our tests where we mock timer observables with the following pattern.

```
let timerObserver: Observer<any>;

 beforeEach(() => {
 spyOn(Observable, 'timer').and.returnValue(Observable.create(
    ((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      timerObserver  = observer;
    })
  ));
});

it(`should not have any notifications by default`, () => {
   timerObserver.next('');
   ...
});
```

Does anybody know how to migrate this pattern across?

---

**Edit:** I've created a simplified illustration of the problem here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6-testing-template-nm7add

```
// Hello.Component
      ngOnInit() {
        const timer$ = timer(30);
        timer$.subscribe(() => {
          this.testMe = 'this has been changed';
        });
      }

// Hello.component.spec
  it('should set testMe after a given timer', fakeAsync(() => {
    tick(50);
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.testMe).toBe('this has been changed');
  }));
```

In this example, I'm trying to get timer to trigger without waiting for the timer to resolve.

Comment: Use the `VirtualTimeScheduler` instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43108109/6680611). Or - even better - use a [marble test](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/marble-testing.md).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cartant. If I understand correctly I can use VirtualTimeScheduler to create timer observables within my spec, but what I'm trying to do is mock a timer that is created within my component, and which I therefore don't have direct access to.

Comment: OK, if you're using `fakeAsync`, you can rely upon it mocking `setInterval` - which is what RxJS uses in its `AsyncScheduler` - but you will need to clobber the `asyncScheduler`'s `now` method to return `fakeAsync`'s concept of the current time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47564162/6680611) for a clobbering mechanism. (Although, `async` is now named `asyncScheduler`.) Unclobbered, `now` will be call `Date.now()` and [that won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48264151/6680611) with `fakeAsync`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you are using `fakeAsync`, you can rely upon its patching of `setInterval` to fake the implementation of the `timer` observable.

However, you will need to clobber the `asyncScheduler` instance's `now` method, as it returns `Date.now()`. (Strictly speaking, this isn't necessary for the `timer` observable, as  you've used it, but it will matter for some other observables - e.g. the observable returned by the `delay` operator).

You can get things to work pretty easily if you use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to clobber the `now` method and to configure a function that keeps track of the fake time:

```ts
import { fakeAsync, tick as _tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { asyncScheduler, of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

describe('fakeAsync and RxJS', () => {

  let tick: (milliseconds: number) => void;

  beforeEach(() => {
    let fakeNow = 0;
    tick = milliseconds => {
      fakeNow += milliseconds;
      _tick(milliseconds);
    };
    asyncScheduler.now = () => fakeNow;
  });

  it('should support timer with fakeAsync', fakeAsync(() => {
    const source = timer(100);
    let received: number | undefined;
    source.subscribe(value => received = value);
    tick(50);
    expect(received).not.toBeDefined();
    tick(50);
    expect(received).toBe(0);
  }));

  it('should support delay with fakeAsync', fakeAsync(() => {
    const source = of(0).pipe(delay(100));
    let received: number | undefined;
    source.subscribe(value => received = value);
    tick(50);
    expect(received).not.toBeDefined();
    tick(50);
    expect(received).toBe(0);
  }));

  afterEach(() => {
    delete asyncScheduler.now;
  });
});
```

---

Actually, because relying upon `fakeAsync` to mock the time-based observable is likely to be useful, I've added a `fakeSchedulers` function to my [`rxjs-marbles`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles) package. See [`fake-spec.ts`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles/blob/master/examples/jasmine/fake-spec.ts) for example usage.

The implementation is basically the same as that in the above snippet - just wrapped up in a function.

---

Since writing this answer and adding `fakeSchedulers` to `rxjs-marbles`, I've written an article about [Testing with Fake Time](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-testing-with-fake-time-94114271eed2).

Comment: Thanks, this was conceptually difficult for me to grasp but you've helped me a lot.
For those that are interested in supplementing the given explanation, and seeing how timer leans on asyncScheduler, I'd recommend a quick look at the source:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/febe2ae4f7b29feeaf6bd4ccbdf623ead5045e24/src/internal/observable/timer.ts