# How to mock RXJS timer() in jasmine test?

Tags: jasmine, rxjs, karma-jasmine, rxjs6

I have an angular component that polls for new data, and while we are waiting for a response it updates a message in the UI every X seconds.  It cycles through a simple string array of messages to show.

Once the correct data is received, we navigate to the appropriate page.

```js
this.pollSubscription = timer(0, pollTimeInSeconds)
    .pipe(
        //convert each observable iteration into an interval in seconds
        map((count: number) => count * pollTimeInSeconds),
        //keep going if we are below the max poll time
        takeWhile((time: number) => time < this.maxPollTime),
        //update the UI message
        tap((time: number) => this.updateCurrentMessage(time)),
        //
        switchMap(() => this.getDataOrError$())
    )
    .subscribe(
        //navigate to the correct page
        (d: IData) => this.navigateBasedOnStatus(d),
        //If an error occurs, OR the observable completes (which should not happen), navigate to the error page
        () => this.navigateToError(),
        () => this.navigateToError()
    );
```

I want to test this behavior, but I'm not entirely sure how to mock the `timer` for this situation.  I saw [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50770564/79677) but I wasn't able to make that work for my situation.

Ideally I'd like to structure a test somewhat like this to ensure that each message shows and that if the timer goes longer than expected it loops back around to the first message:

```js
it('should show every status as the timer changes', fakeAsync(() => {
    tick(0);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(debugEl.nativeElement.innerText.trim()).toEqual('Message one');

    tick(1000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(debugEl.nativeElement.innerText.trim()).toEqual('Message two');

    tick(2000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(debugEl.nativeElement.innerText.trim()).toEqual('Message three');

    //etc...
}));
```

---

**EDIT** I'm including a new attempt at testing this based on some comments below, but this is stil not working

```js
let timerTick: (milliseconds: number) => void;

beforeEach(() => {
    let fakeNow = 0;
    timerTick = (milliseconds: number): void => {
        fakeNow += milliseconds;
        tick(milliseconds);
    };
    asyncScheduler.now = (): number => fakeNow;
});

afterEach(() => {
    delete asyncScheduler.now;
});

it('should show every status as the timer changes', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges(); // triggers ngOnInit()

    const pollTimeInSeconds = loginPollTime * 1000;
    let received: number | undefined;
    timer(0, pollTimeInSeconds, asyncScheduler).subscribe((value: number) => received = value);
    console.log(received);

    timerTick(0);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(debugEl.nativeElement.innerText.trim()).toEqual('Message one');
    console.log(received)

    timerTick(pollTimeInSeconds);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(debugEl.nativeElement.innerText.trim()).toEqual('Message two');
    console.log(received)

    timerTick(pollTimeInSeconds * 2);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(debugEl.nativeElement.innerText.trim()).toEqual('Message three');
    console.log(received)
}));
```

The jasmine output is:

```
Expected 'Message one' to equal 'Message two'.
Expected 'Message one' to equal 'Message three'.
```

The console output is:

```
> undefined
> 0
> 1
> 3
```

Comment: "... wasn't able to make that work for my situation." Why?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with RXJS so that code just didn't seem to work when I tried it.  I was not able to get it to increment the timer no matter what I did.  If you think it would work with some changes I'd love to see what they are!

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md but in general you need to pass an instance of `TestScheduler` to `timer(x, y, testSchedulerInstance)`

Comment: @martin check my updated post, I've tried out what I think should be working here... but I'm having no luck