# how to automatically call discardPeriodicTasks after tests in Angular with jest?

Tags: angular, jestjs

I do a one time subscription that has a `debounceTime` pipe on my component `onInit`:

```
this.subscriptions.add(
  this.updateJobs$
    .pipe(
      filter(jobs => !!jobs.length),
      debounceTime(MyComponent.ListStabilizationTimeInMS),
      first(),
    )
    .subscribe((jobs: Update[]) => {
      // some code
    })
);
```

Because of this I need to include `discardPeriodicTasks();` as last line after each `fakeAsync` tests, which I find tedious. Otherwise I get the error `Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.` for all the tests.

I tried to create an `afterEach`:

```
afterEach(()=> {
  discardPeriodicTasks();
});

afterEach(fakeAsync(()=> {
  discardPeriodicTasks();
}));
```

But it does not work and the only way to pass the tests is to manually append `discardPeriodicTasks();` to all the test cases. Would be great if it could be automated.

Comment: Could you post your whole component code along with the test setup (`TestBed...`) and tests in question?

Comment: Hi @PhilippMeissner I am not using TestBed, I am doing unit tests without Angular environment `sut = new MyComponent(mockedProdiver1, mockedProdiver2, mockedProdiver3)`

Comment: Still, the entire code base to the problem would help a lot to potentially identify an issue.

Comment: I had the same error with `fakeAsync` and it seems that this error("Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.") only caused when a test fails. Try to run a test with success and take a look if an error persists.

Comment: @andriishupta I have a lot of test there, all correct and passing. After I add `debounceTime` they break.

Comment: Because they don't use a virtual testing timer. Such as I don't see test code, so: are you sure tick/flush, etc is used correctly? also, have found something that might help you - clearing the timer manually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093935/how-to-unit-test-a-function-is-called-correctly-after-a-timer-has-fired-angular

Comment: @andriishupta I can not paste the code because it is sadly proprietary.. I know that a flush of the periodic task is needed I am just looking for a way to do always for each tests.

Comment: @distante can you at least create a dummy component and replicate issue somewhere and share?