# Unit tests for ngrx-effect fails

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am writing unit tests for my effect.ts file. But for some reason, it passes even if I change the expect statement to dispatch ContactInfoFailed action. Is there a problem with the subscription in my test file? I am unable to figure out what exactly is the root cause of this! Or if there is a better way to write this test?
Please find below my effect and it's test case.

// effects.ts

```
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { ContactTriageService } from '../views/contact-triage/contact-triage.service';
import {
  CONTACT_INFO_RESPONSE_REQUESTED, ContactInfoSucceeded, ContactInfoFailed , 
  CONTACT_INFO_SELECTION_RESPONSE_REQUESTED, ContactInfoSelectionSucceeded, 
  ContactInfoSelectionFailed,
  ContactInfoServiceResponse
} from '../actions/actions';
import { mergeMap, map, catchError, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ContactInfoEffect {
  @Effect()
  fetchContactInfoResponse = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(CONTACT_INFO_RESPONSE_REQUESTED),
    delay(250),
        mergeMap((action) =>
            this.contactTriageService.getContentInfo().
            pipe(map((contacts) => new ContactInfoSucceeded(contacts)),           
            catchError(() => of(new ContactInfoFailed()))
             ),
        )
  )

  constructor(
    private actions: Actions,
    private contactTriageService: ContactTriageService
  ) { }
}
```

// effects.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of, ReplaySubject, Subject, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { provideMockActions } from '@ngrx/effects/testing';
import { ContactInfoEffect } from './effects';
import { ContactTriageService } from '../views/contact-triage/contact-triage.service';
import { reducers } from '../reducers/reducers';
import { ContactInfoSucceeded } from '../actions/actions';
import { getContactInfoMock } from 'src/server/test/mocks';
import { ContactInfoResponse } from 'src/server/contact-info/interfaces/contact-info.interface';

describe('ContactInfoEffect', () => {
  let effects: ContactInfoEffect;
  let contactTriageService: ContactTriageService;
  let actions: Subject<any>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)],
      providers: [
        ContactInfoEffect,
        {
          provide: ContactTriageService,
          useValue: {
            getContentInfo() {
              return EMPTY;
            }
          }
        },
        provideMockActions(() => actions)
      ]
    });
    effects = TestBed.get(ContactInfoEffect);
    contactTriageService = TestBed.get(ContactTriageService);
  });

  it('should dispatch `ContactInfoSucceeded` if the service returns successfully', () => {
    const response:ContactInfoResponse =  getContactInfoMock();
    const contactTriageServiceSpy = spyOn(
        contactTriageService,
      'getContentInfo'
    ).and.returnValue(of( [
        getContactInfoMock()
      ]));
    actions = new ReplaySubject(1);
    actions.next(new ContactInfoSucceeded(getContactInfoMock()));
    effects.fetchContactInfoResponse.subscribe((result) => {   
      expect(result).toEqual(new ContactInfoSucceeded(response));
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason that could make your test don't work as expected is the **delay() operator**. The delay() operator is making your stream/Effect totally **asynchronous**.

In order to correctly test an asynchronous stream like that you should make your **test assertion async**, or more recommended, you can schedule synchronously your stream **by mocking the scheduler**. Here are some useful links where is discussed and explained:

[Testing and mocking lettable operators in RxJS 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355666/testing-and-mocking-lettable-operators-in-rxjs-5-5)

https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/180

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25457

As you can see, is a common problem, and the solution is not perfect in any case.

Tip: you can try to remove temporarily the delay() operator and see if it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying Llorenc, even if I remove delay it doesn't work correctly

Comment: Hmm interesting, can you share the 'test' output if there is? It think that maybe the problem is that the callback on the 'subscribe' is never called right? I think this line could be the problem: actions = new ReplaySubject(1);
I mean, it seems it should go before the provideMockActions() function, since if you create a new Subject after, this new subject doesn't have any subscriber.